# jquery,ajax,php image upload in not working

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a jquery,ajax,php file uploading script, but it's not working.

I don't receive any value in php page using '`$_FILES["file"]["type"]`' .

My HTML code is like this: `<input name="file" type="file" id="file" />`

My jQuery code is:

```
$.ajax({    
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mdi.php',     
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 7000,
    success: function(datas) {          
        $('#disp').removeClass().addClass((datas.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
        .html(datas.msg).fadeIn('fast');
```

Comment: What's the data variable? Do you receive any values in the $_FILES global? `var_dump($_FILES);` will tell you.

Comment: Can files be uploaded through AJAX though?

Comment: @Svish: You've never uploaded an image for an SO post, then. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Doesn't it use an iframe for that? If you look at the html in FireBug you'll see that there is an iframe with name upload-iframe, so I assume it is used for uploading...?

Answer (score 0):

make sure youre using the following enctype in your form: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: yes i am using the same encryption type and its working  with out jquery or ajax.One more thing is i am trying create a use profile updation page so i am trying to upload image with other data's like user's name,dob,gender..etc. is this a problem ?